# run time error 1004 unable to set the hidden property of the range class

Tags: excel, vba

I get the run time error when I open the workbook. The open function works great without the close function, but as soon as I add the close function I get the error. Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Range("A1:Z1")
If cell.Value = "X" Then
cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
Next cell

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Protect "1962"
Next ws

ThisWorkbook.Protect "1962", True

ThisWorkbook.Save


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you protect the worksheet in the BeforeClose routine. Hence the Workbook_Open doesn't have access to update it the next time it is being opened. Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "1962"            '<<<<
    For Each cell In Range("A1:Z1")
    If cell.Value = "X" Then
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
    Next cell
    ActiveSheet.Protect "1962"              '<<<<

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on protected worksheets, so in general unprotecting is not the answer.

Another possibility is rogue group boxes (as was my case). To check for this, go to Home...Find and Select...Selection Pane. Unhide all rows and columns in you worksheet. Click on each name in the Selection panel and it will reveal the control for you to verify. Unless you have changed them, all group boxes will have a name starting with "Group Box".